# Why do we get a 'None' item when appending an item to an existing list?

Tags: python, list

Use case:
I want to append a new item along with all the existing items in a list to the same list.
Ex:

```
list = [ 'a', 'b', 'c']
```

Appending `'d'`, expecting the output as: `['a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd']`

My code:

```
list.append(list.append('d'))
```

Current output:

```
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', None]
```

Why am I getting a `None` item here and how can I print the list as expected?

Comment: Note: One should avoid shadowing built-in names like `list`. I would recommend using a different variable name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`list.append` returns `None`. This is because `list.append` is an *in-place* operation. In addition, you are shadowing a built-in, which is not recommended.

You *can* `append` to a copy, then `extend` your original list:

```
L = ['a', 'b', 'c']
L_to_append = L.copy()
L_to_append.append('d')
L.extend(L_to_append)
```

But this is verbose. You can just use the `+=` operator:

```
L = ['a', 'b', 'c']
L += L + ['d']

print(L)

['a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `list.append('d')` instead.

`append` function in `list` return nothing and so `list.append(list.append('d'))` will be added `None`.

To print the expected list (let the list be 'l'):

```
list_old = list(l)
l += l # ['a', 'b', 'c'] -> ['a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'c']
l.append('d')
list_old.extend(l)
```